# Would be vs would have been

Tags: modal-verbs, past-perfect

I came across a sentece while I was reading a novel,It says that:

> It wasn't much of a park,some trees and benches and a bronze statue of some former mayor or someone who would have been embarrased to have this image in a park that had gone as crummy as that one.

So my question is that how would the meaning of the sentence change if used who would be embarrased instead of who would have been embarrased and what is the exact meaning difference between those 2?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only difference is that "would be embarrassed" suggests there is a chance that the former mayor or whoever it is might turn up and suffer that embarrassment - whereas "would have been embarrassed" suggests this is no longer possible, because the former mayor is probably dead by now.